# How to put a js promise inside a function that resolves the promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

Promises are thenable but I want the value returned as a value not a promise.

promiseFulfilled = arg => {        // this function CANNOT return a promise !
let definiteAnswer = 'unresolved'
crazyPromse(arg)      // this promise (elsewhere) has a  1 sec timeout and always resolves with 'desired result'
.then( neededAnswer => {
definiteAnswer = neededAnswer
})
return definiteAnswer
}
console.log(promiseFulfilled(arg))   //  do I get 'desired result' or 'unresolved'

Comment: You cannot do that. Once asynchronicity is involved, you can't get away from it.

Comment: you can't. see e.g. https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html

Comment: In the linked question marked as duplicate, read the answer about *async/await* - it's probably what you meant to do.